# Rails: belongs_to twice on same field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please, anyone know, can I declare relation `belongs_to` twice to same field?

For example:

```
class Notice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :avia, foreign_key: 'ticket_id', class_name: 'AviaTicket'
  belongs_to :bus, foreign_key: 'ticket_id', class_name: 'BusTicket'
end
```

In this way, I have use `ticket_id` twice for different models. And on `belongs_to` side its doen't work, but on otherside(`AviaTicket`, `BusTicket`) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `belongs_to` in rails, you are implying that the model has a foreign key that has an `id` of the table that it belongs to. You are allowed to have as much `belongs_to` relationships as you want, however, they all have to have a different foreign_key. Your foreign keys should be specific to the tables you are referring to, for example, AviaTicket's foreign key should be `foreign_key: 'avia_ticket_id'` and same goes for `BusTicket`, the foreign key should be specific to that table, that way rails knows what foreign key to look for when trying to find the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, solved! Answer is Yes.
It doen't work because I've use `modules` in `/models` dir. And I forgot `::`

And right declare with my modules:

```
//app/models/notice/notice.rb

class Notice::Notice < ApplicationRecord
.
.
  belongs_to :bus, foreign_key: 'ticket_id', class_name: '::BusTicket'
.
.
end
```